# Why developer name showing "No results found for pub:" on Google play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I have published android application on googple play store. When i clicked and developer name it showing "No results found for pub:".

Comment: What kind of key did you sign your app with? If you signed it with a debug key that's the reason.

Comment: Now its showing correctly. thanks